# How to exclude all items except 1 from the UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I search a solution to remove all items from the `UIActivityViewController`, exclude 1 item.
I used `excludedActivityTypes` with a big list of UIActivityType, but it is not suffisant.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like a whitelist for the UIActivityController. So you have to exclude all activities you don't want to be displayed.

Of course, there is a risk that future activities that your app does not yet know will still be displayed.
To avoid this, you might want to build your own UI. This depends on which activity you want to display.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your feedback!